# .NET web 2.0 API, 503 Service unavailable

Tags: rest, web-services, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-503

I created a **.NET web 2.0 REST GET API**. which reads reads a **large XML file** and then **insert the data in Database (SQL Server)**. But when I run the API, then, after some time browser/Rest-Client returns **503 service unavailable** message. Works fine when I run the API on localhost, but gives the above error when I publish my app and connect to Live Server.

I also tried with custom built API client (windows forms app), that sends my REST GET API call. and after the some specific time, it gives this error:

> GetWebResponse: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

1- **Goto IIS ->Click Application Pool -> right pane click the name of service and start the process**

2- have you give IUSER  security to access the service remotely if not then check it and give permission to access

3- add firewall rule to allow traffic

Comment: The process status is already **Started**. still not working. I updated the description. kindly check.